# C#, Autofac: NamedParameter is not provided in Register<>

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, autofac

I'm trying some autofac features at the moment and are struggling with the NamedParameter.

I created a very simple example, where `IFoo` is realized by `HappyFoo` and `SadFoo`. `IFooUser` expects an `IFoo` object in the constructor and uses it to print something to the console.

The code below shows how I'm trying to build a `IFooUser` object which shall use an `IFoo` object based on a 'score' value.

```
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterType<NormalFooUser>().As<IFooUser>();

        builder.Register<IFoo>((context, parameters) =>
        {
            var score = parameters.Named<int>("score"); // ! Exception !
            if (score >= 100)
            {
                return new HappyFoo();
            } 
            return new SadFoo();
        });

        var container = builder.Build();

        using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            scope.Resolve<IFooUser>(new NamedParameter("score", 90)).useFoo();
        }
```

Unfortunately when I execute this code, the `parameters` sequence doesn't hold any values => Exception! When I resolve to `IFoo`everything works fine:

```
       scope.Resolve<IFoo>(new NamedParameter("score", 90)).foo(); // Works
```

But this is not what I want to do. So I'm wondering how I can construct a `IFooUser` with an `IFoo` object corresponding to the 'score' with the NamedParameter.

The complete code-sample can be found [here as gist](https://gist.github.com/codefluent-de/1b6adbdb9615d3bb8849e81a0f8b66b5)

Thanks.

Comment: [This is an FAQ in the docs.](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/injecting-global-parameters.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NamedParameter` is intended to configure the requested component and not the whole dependency graph, the parameter is not propagated through the whole registration process it is not a *context* parameter.

If you want to have a *context* you can implement such a component which will store some properties.

```
// interface 
interface IContext {
    T Get<T>(String name); 
    void Set<T>(String name, T value); 
}

// registration 
builder.RegisterType<FooContext>().As<IContext>();
builder.Register<IFoo>(c =>
{
    var score = c.Resolve<IContext>().Get<Int32>("score"); 
    if (score >= 100)
    {
        return new HappyFoo();
    }
    return new SadFoo();
});


// usage 
using (ILifetimeScope scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
    scope.Resolve<IContext>().Set("score", 90); 
    scope.Resolve<IFooUser>().useFoo();
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that you can set the context property whenever you want in your current lifetime scope. You can also imagine implementation without `Set` method which will retrieve value based on whatever you want.

Another way of doing the same thing is by using a `Func<Int32, IFoo>` dependency and the `TypedAs` methods

```
builder.Register<IFoo>((c, p) =>
{
    Int32 score = p.TypedAs<Int32>(); 
    if (score >= 100)
    {
        return new HappyFoo();
    }
    return new SadFoo();
});
```

and of course you have to change the `IFooUser` interface and implementation

```
public class NormalFooUser : IFooUser
{
    private readonly Func<Int32, IFoo> _fooBuilder;

    public NormalFooUser(Func<Int32,IFoo> fooBuilder)
    {
        _fooBuilder = fooBuilder;
    }

    public void useFoo(Int32 score)
    {
        _fooBuilder(score).foo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
scope.Resolve<IFooUser>(new NamedParameter("score", 90))
```

tells Autofac it should use the parameter `score` to create the instance registered as `IFooUser`, but actually it does not need it - its dependency `IFoo` needs it. Autofac does not automatically pass these parameters down to type's dependency, you need to do it by yourself, simply passing parameters on registration for `IFooUser`

```
builder.Register((c, p) => new NormalFooUser(c.Resolve<IFoo>(p))).As<IFooUser>();
```

This snippet passes all parameters used to resolve `IFooUser`, you can limit it only to these required

```
builder.Register((c, p) => new NormalFooUser(c.Resolve<IFoo>(new NamedParameter("score", p.Named<int>("score"))))).As<IFooUser>();
```