# Supply typed parameter to nested dependencies in Autofac

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I was under the impression that the `TypedParameter` could be used to supply values during resolution in Autofac.

However, it seems that these parameters are used on the explicit type being resolved only, and does not propagate down the dependency chain.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

```
public interface IDepA { }

public interface IDepB { }

public interface IDepC { }

public class DepA : IDepA
{
    public DepA(IDepB depB) { }

}

public class DepB : IDepB
{
    public DepB(IDepC depC) { }
}

public class DepC : IDepC { }

[TestMethod]
public void AutofacResolutionTest()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    builder.RegisterType<DepA>().As<IDepA>();
    builder.RegisterType<DepB>().As<IDepB>();

    var container = builder.Build();
    // Works
    var b = container.Resolve<IDepB>(new TypedParameter(typeof(IDepC), new DepC()));
    // Does not work
    var a = container.Resolve<IDepA>(new TypedParameter(typeof(IDepC), new DepC()));
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55110266/c-autofac-namedparameter-is-not-provided-in-register

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: You can't pass a parameter to something in the middle of a resolve chain.

[This is an FAQ in the Autofac docs.](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/injecting-global-parameters.html)

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to revise my design for the n-th time.

Comment: This is really disappointing. I'm starting to regret leaving Ninject, it handled this and also changing registrations during runtime just fine. Saying "this is probably a design issue on your side" is not enough, sometimes there are legitimate reasons, albeit uncommon, where it needs to be done.

Comment: It appears you can get around this with scoped registrations (basically register the instance for the scope then resolve inside the scope): https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/working-with-scopes.html